# An unbiased estimator for distance between two observed categorical distributions?

Tags: distributions, entropy, hellinger

I have two empirical categorical distributions: P and q with |P| >> |q|.

P is the full description of my population, so I treat it as the reference baseline distribution. q, however, is a much smaller observed sample which I hypothesize to be coming from an unobserved distribution Q. All I know about Q is q.

Is there a way to estimate a notion of how representative Q is with respect to P? E.g., Hellinger distance, KL-divergence, etc? I need a measure that doesn't depend on the size of q as I will estimate these distances for different observed samples coming from different distributions: Q, R, V and compare them to see which one is closer to P in that regard. With empirically computed Hellinger distance or KL-divergence between P and q, the values depend on the size of q due to sampling variance and larger samples end up seeming closer to P.